# How to add Icon to the window in maya using python

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

**Code:**

```
import maya.cmds as cmd

cmd.window(title='GUI')

cmd.showWindow()
```

This code creates a window with title and i want to add Icon too .Can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Where in the window do you want to add the icon to? A concept sketch/wireframe would help.

Comment: You may use maya api and use wrapinstance()

Comment: @python_fan did you have a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can not change the icon directly. But you can change it if you get access to underlying Qt widgets.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from maya import OpenMayaUI as omui

# Special cases for different Maya versions
try:
    from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
except ImportError:
    from shiboken import wrapInstance

try:
    from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget
except ImportError:
    from PySide.QtGui import QIcon, QWidget

# Create a window and save its name    
window = cmds.window(title='GUI')

# Show the newly created window
cmds.showWindow(window)

# Get a pointer and convert it to Qt Widget object
qw = omui.MQtUtil.findWindow(window)
widget = wrapInstance(long(qw), QWidget)

# Create a QIcon object
icon = QIcon('/path/to/icon.png')

# Assign the icon
widget.setWindowIcon(icon)
```